# Mariasql with nodejs not working

Tags: mariadb, mariasql

I did:

```
var MariaSQLClient = require('mariasql');

var maria_connection = new MariaSQLClient({ host: '127.0.0.1', user: 'root', password: 'root', db: 'db1' })
```

But when i check whether it is connected or not using:

```
maria_connection.connected
```

> false

It returns false always